# Should I back-transform estimate and 95%CI after a survival analysis with log-normal distribution?

Tags: survival, lognormal-distribution, back-transformation

I need to run a survival analysis on my data. Based on the AIC, the **lognormal** distribution is the most suited one. Can I report the estimates and 95% CI as they are, or do they need back-transformation because of the lognormal distribution? If so, how do I back-transform them?

**Code:**

```
fit.hbe.rev1 <- survreg(Surv(Latency_revisit,eventrev)~factor(Genetics)+
                          factor(Incubation)+
                          factor(Round)+
                          factor(Genetics):factor(Incubation)+
                          cluster(PenR),
                        data=HBE,dist="lognormal")
summary(fit.hbe.rev1)
confint(fit.hbe.rev1)
```

Comment: I don't think that AIC can be used to compare different model families.  I'd go with specific goodness of fit assessments such as normality of residuals and constant variance - see [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/psmcase).  And back-transforming depends on your choice of estimand.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated? Please edit the question to say more about the specific estimates whose CI are in question. Are you just talking about the model's coefficient estimates? Or are you interested in things like median survival estimates at particular values of covariates? Also, please explain why you think that the use of an underlying log-normal distribution (or any other parametric survival distribution) might affect the CI of either of those.